# GDB not running program (Mac OS)

Tags: c, gdb

I use gdb to run my program but it doesn't work with it. It returns warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
Cannot access memory at address 0xf726 
I didn't set any breakpoint. I am not sure is it the problem of gdb and how could I fix it?
Here is the result I got:

```
rihiroshibitekiMacBook-Pro:desktop Richard$ gdb test
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from test...Reading symbols from 
/Users/Richard/Desktop/test.dSYM/
Contents/Resources/DWARF/test...done.
done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/Richard/Desktop/test 
[New Thread 0x1903 of process 776]
[New Thread 0x1c03 of process 776]
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
Cannot access memory at address 0xf726
Command aborted.
```

Comment: What flags did you use to compile your program?

Comment: Make sure you have compiled for debugging with the -g flag as Alex Quilliam mentioned.

Comment: Before `r`, issue `d` command to delete all breakpoints perhaps?

Comment: I use gcc -g test.c -o test

Comment: I did compile it and there is definitely no breakpoints.

Comment: This problem continues with gdb-8.1.1  Worse, it doesn't seem to know how to load a core file on macOS 10.13.6 either (`no core file handler recognizes format`)